# Decreasing page load time with Solspace Freeform

Tags: templates, solspace-freeform, forms, cache, ce-cache

I wanted to see if anyone had any suggestions on how to optimize the speed of Solspace Freeform.

We've noticed the template caching doesn't help as it generates random numbers in hidden tags combined with the usage of captcha there seems to be few fays to decrease page load times.

Would using CE Cache improve the performance?

Answer (score 1):

Currently Freeform does not natively support being cached as it generates a params_id and XID hash on page load that is not reusable due to security concerns.

You could, in theory, cache the form, then on submit (or first field change?), use ajax to fetch an uncached version of the same form template and pull the params_id and XID from that uncached form and inject it into the cached form before submit.